# Get data from different tables using inner joins

Tags: laravel, join

I have column in results as 'user_id','test','subject' and in datatable i want to get the 'test_name' which is saved in 'tests' table, Student name 'name' saved in 'users' and 'subject name' in table 'subjects' in column 'subjects' now tell me what is the best way to get this data.

So far i had tried this but getting null while dumping.

```
 $result = DB::table('results')
->where([
    ['results.subject',$request->subject],
    ['test',$request->test],
    ['user_id',$request->name]
])
 ->join('users','results.user_id','=','users.name')
->join('tests','tests.id','=','results.test')
->join('subjects','subjects.id','=','results.subject')
->select('results.*','users.name','tests.test_name','subjects.subjects As s_subject')
->first();

dd($result);
```

anyone who can guide me the best possible solution.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the power of the Eloquent model of Laravel. You have to create Results model class as follow(and obviously need to create User, Test and Subject model class)

**Results.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Results extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * Get the user profile associated with the results.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the test details associated with the results.
     */
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Test', 'test');
    }

    /**
     * Get the subject associated with the results.
     */
    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Subject', 'subject');
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
$results = App\Results::where(['subject' => $request->subject, 'test' => $request->test, 'user_id' => $request->name])->first();
```

Now you will get the Result object with the test, subject, and test property.

**Note that:- You should provide the output when you are asking any question.**